# Удалить записи из Set Aerospike

Tags: java, aerospike

Пользуюсь Aerospike клиентом.

Надо удалить записи из Set. Раньше я их удалял поштучно в цикле. Т.е. выгружаешь их и итерируешь с поштучным удалением. Но записей стало слишком много, что я стал получать ошибку:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space

В самом Aerospike я очищал сет такой командой:

```
asinfo -v "set-config:context=namespace;id=mynamespace;set=myset;set-delete=true;"
```

Есть ли способ очистить set без загрузки всех его данных и поштучным удалением?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [truncate](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info#truncate) command.

`asinfo -v "truncate:namespace= mynamespace;set=myset"`

Comment: Can Aerospike client execute truncate command?

Comment: Yes it can. The Aerospike client can execute any info commands. The following article should help: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-do-i-run-asinfo-commands-from-the-client/1373